# Custom CategoryAttribute does not work if defined in a referenced assembly

Tags: nunit, resharper

I created a demo custom CategoryAttribute in the same assembly as my test fixture:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAttribute : CategoryAttribute
{
}

[Custom]
[TestFixture]
public class SomeTests
{

}
```

Everything was great. ReSharper's Unit Test Explorer found the test fixture, and I could then sort by the new "Custom" category.

To avoid duplicating the new custom attribute in every test assembly, I moved the attribute definition to a shared assembly. However, this causes the category to "go away" in the Unit Test Explorer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you try running under alternative runners it should indicate whether the problem is with NUnit or the R# runner.

Comment: No problem is indicated. Not sure what you mean by "it". I'm using ReSharper's Unit Test Explorer window, and the expected category is either in the list or not in the list depending on where the attribute is defined.

Comment: "It" means the runner. We already know (from you) that the R# runner doesn't recognize the category. It may help to see what happens under a different runner, such as the nunit console runner.